# Bold ExecCommand in Firefox not working

Tags: javascript, firefox, selection, bold, execcommand

I was using execCommand in order to make the text on my WYSIWYG editor bold. The command was working fine but now for some reason in Firefox 14.0.1 it stopped working. What happens is that if I have a text and make it bold and then save, I get something like this, (this is what I want to have, so so far it is ok):

```
 <span font-weight: bold;">hello</span>
```

The problem now is that if I select again the text in order to remove the bold, Firefox does not understand the font-weight attribute so it adds the b tag again in my text. This is not happening in Firefox 10, Chrome or IE for example. There the browser understands and just remove the font-weight.

So my question is if someone knows something about that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you've also called `document.execCommand("StyleWithCSS", false, true);`? I can't replicate this on Firefox 14.0.1 on my machine. http://jsfiddle.net/sJy6j/1/

Comment: No I do not called this one. Should I?

Comment: I assumed you had because Firefox defaults to using `<b>` elements rather than `<span style="font-weight: bold">`. It's up to you which you'd prefer.

Comment: well I think this one fixed my problem. I just added that and I think is working now. Thanks a lot!!